# What can I do to transcribe the vocals in this metal track?

Tags: transcription

The part that I am most curious about is the chorus (first one at 2:00, if you wish to listen to as little as possible =) ).

[Lorna Shore - To the Hellfire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VO3NSHk3wl0)

Background: I just found out about LilyPond and realized I could use it to make custom sheet music. As a first test I chose to write the sheet music for this song as it was the first song that I could think of that cannot be represented by standard music notation software. When I had transcribed the guitar and the rhythm/duration of the vocals it hit me that even though I can't distinguish any individual notes in the vocals, that doesn't mean there are none.

Comment: @Mathphyte - i need to ask you to read not only our [ask] page, but also our whole site [about] - the community is trying to help you edit your question to be appropriate for this site, and to follow the rules, and you are honestly being rather rude. Continuing this behaviour will result in a suspension.

Comment: I have edited the question to actually focus on something that is objective and can be answered here. The comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134551/discussion-on-question-by-mathphyte-what-can-i-do-to-transcribe-the-vocals-in-th).

Comment: I saw sheet notation in a book somewhere that used some kind of squiggly contour line, no idea what name it had but perhaps that could be something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible. And no, this does not by any means require perfect pitch. It *does* require a trained ear.

But we need to keep some things in mind:

1. Transcription is usually a means for either study or reproduction. It is inherently hard to to reproduce such vocal technique on the exact pitch (though not impossible). It is thus questionable if such an exact transcription makes sense.
2. This kind of vocal style is inherently non-harmonic. This means that we do not have the notion of a root frequency and (up to inharmonicity) multiples of it, but we get a much more complex spectrum. While we *can* extract certain dominant pitch ranges this makes clearly saying "This is the current pitch" quite arbitrary. An exact transcription of this would thus need a transcription in chords of the most important pitch centers. Of course we then also have the problem that many of these pitches are non chromatic, so notating this stuff would need microtonal notation.
3. The backing track sometimes makes it unclear what actual pitches you have, which might lead us in assuming certain root frequencies because our brain expects them to be there.

This makes an exact transcription in pitches quite hard (also anyone who claims they can immediadely pick out the dominant frequency is overselling his subjective viewpoint, as it is hard to define an objective "dominant frequency"). But at the very least we can say: This vocal part was sung with some clear intended melody. And this melody can be transcribed quite easily. The chorus in question does for example alternate between A-flat and G (i.e. tonic-dominant).

Finally some remarks about the question: The question in itself is fine imo, but the title absolutely unuseful (it states a *request* instead of describing the question) and your whole questions kind of avoids asking the actual question and instead goes about with warnings and requests.

Imo the question would be better phrased somewhat like:
Is it possible to pitch transcribe Metal vocals?
I’m currently transcribing this metal piece (link) and wondered if etc ...

In my opinion a question is phrased well if a reader can identify the rough outline of the question by reading the title (and eventually by overlooking the first paragraph).

Comment: Yes, "metal" is a hugely helpful qualifier. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity regarding the intended melody that you described. If you don't mind me asking, do you know where I could find someone to transcribe that melody (or not transcribed per se, I don't want timing or durations, just pitches)? And what do you think it would cost? I have no idea about where to turn or if it's even worth it.

Comment: @Mathphyte The last time I looked into hiring someone for a transcription, about 15 years ago, it was $150USD / minute of music. There are professionals who do this kind of work. But as a starting point, you might look on a site like MuseScore, which contains a lot of transcriptions. Find some you like, and contact the person who did them.

Comment: Weird, I thought I heard E flats and less (strict) alternation in the chorus along with at least one A flat.

Comment: @Aaron Haha, wow! That was ridiculously expensive. For this song that would be $900 for like ten minutes of work. Thanks you very much for that comment! Spared me from trying to find someone to transcribe it. This is just a side project, so I think I'll stick with a percussion line for the vocals =D

Comment: @Mathphyte I’m sure the numbers Aaron gave are about transcription of more complex things as just a vocal melody. Transcribing complex arrangements is a lot of  work, and that amount reflects the numbers of hours the transciber has to invest. Transcribing a simple melody is quite tame. I’d say I could do the whole thing in less than two hours.

Comment: @Mathphyte Even if the task is really only 10 minutes of work, how many years of training and practice would it take to be able to do that task in 10 minutes?

Comment: @Theodore I’m quite sure these rates come from much more complex transcriptions than just a single simple voice.

Comment: @Lazy I'm sure you're right.  I was only making a point about the way skilled effort is often devalued.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect pitch is irrelevant.   RELATIVE pitch will be useful.

This performance is on the borderline between music and noise. We can certainly notate the rhythm. We can find *some* pitch information.  I think it would be almost impossible to write down anything that, without other input, would enable a reasonable approximation of the performance!